# Excited Beginner?

Tags: training

I am beginner and do not want to reduce my weight.My objective is to increase my stimna and leg power.I have an indoor cycle.what should be my daily target and how should it then be increase?

Comment: Help us to help you. You say you want to increase stamina and power. Any exercise programme starts with measuring your current abilities, and setting goals. So what is you current level of endurance, how are you measuring power, and what power are you producing?

Comment: Getting yourself a real bike might help, personally I find nothing more off-putting than indoor training. Then, a target could just be to cycle "to" somewhere and to time yourself.

Comment: Very rough ball park is increase distance (time) 10% per week at same speed/effort to improve endurance. You need at least one long distance/low effort (time) ride per week, other exercises can be shorter duration high intensity. You get fit from recovery - not from exercise. At least 2 days between big sessions. Consider body weight conditioning 1 session per week and work your core and upper body for all round fitness - lunges, squats, press ups, crunches  etc.

Comment: Can you please a more descriptive title for your question. Suggesting "daily target on indoor bike for beginner aiming for weight loss"

Answer (score 1):

I'm a casual biker and casual marathon runner. When I need to improve my biking fitness, I apply the principles from marathon training. Biking is very similar to running and the same fitness components are important. So I pick a typical marathon training schedule, convert distance into time and try to do it as hard as I can, on a bike instead of feet. Typically it's 30-50-30 minutes Tue-Wed-Thu then 50-80 min Sat-Sun the first week, and it keeps increasing about 10% a week. There is many schedules online. Try it.

Comment: Is there such thing as a casual marathon runner?

Answer (score 0):

Well increasing stamina and no weight reduction, requires you to take good diet, a bit more than usual to compensate for the weight loss caused by exercise. the rest is upto your own comfort. you should pedal continuously for 30 minutes plus without stopping, that would increase your stamina at a constant rate.

Comment: Without knowing Mansoor's current fitness levels, we have no idea whether 30 minutes is way too much or way too little.

Comment: well I consider him to be a normal above average fit human, the time can then be adjusted by the trainee as per his fitness level. Thanks for pointing out as I forgot to include this in the answer